How to generate Authenticator QR Code with Blazor .NET 8 in razor component
When using the new Identity razor components from .NET 8 you still get a link to this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-enable-qrcodes?view=aspnetcore-8.0#adding-qr-codes-to-the-2fa-configuration-page
But the article is for _cshtml files, so it does not work for me, as I use the new .razor files and the load event is never triggered. I already tried executing the code in the OnInitializedAsync() method, but there you cannot execute JavaScript code. I also tried using the OnAfterRenderAsync method, but it also never gets called. So, how can I create an Authenticator QR Code in a new Blazor application?

the link you shared is based on  qrcode.js JavaScript library to generate qr code, so that when we want to use it in the razor component, we require to use the raozr component way to call js method.

I tried it but did not work for me,can you give me a code example?

pls share more details about your blazor project, render mode, how do you write your Authentication scheme and related codes

I had the same problem. Thanks to this article I managed to get it working. You only have to install: QRCoderNetCore from PM.
Then in your /Account/Manage/EnableAuthenticator.razor add folowing using directives:
@using QRCoder
@using System.Drawing.Imaging 
@using System.Drawing

Add the QR code to your page:
<li>
    <p>Scan the QR Code or enter this key <kbd>@sharedKey</kbd> into your two factor authenticator app. Spaces and casing do not matter.</p>
                
    <div><img alt="" src="@QRByte" width="300" class="mb-5" /></div>
    <div data-url="@QRByte"></div>
                
    <div></div>
    <div data-url="@authenticatorUri"></div>
</li>

And alter your @Code similar to:
@code {
    private const string AuthenticatorUriFormat = "otpauth://totp/{0}:{1}?secret={2}&issuer={0}&digits=6";

    private string? message;
    private ApplicationUser user = default!; private string? sharedKey;
    private string? authenticatorUri;
    private IEnumerable<string>? recoveryCodes; public string QRByte = ""; [CascadingParameter]
    private HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; } = default!;

    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    private InputModel Input { get; set; } = new();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        user = await UserAccessor.GetRequiredUserAsync(HttpContext); await LoadSharedKeyAndQrCodeUriAsync(user);
    }
    public void GenerateQRCode(string QRUrl)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(QRUrl))
        {
            using MemoryStream ms = new(); QRCodeGenerator qrCodeGenerate = new();

            QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrCodeGenerate.CreateQrCode(QRUrl, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
            QRCode qrCode = new(qrCodeData);
            using Bitmap qrBitMap = qrCode.GetGraphic(20); qrBitMap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
            string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            QRByte = string.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", base64);
        }
    }
    private async Task OnValidSubmitAsync()
    {
        // Strip spaces and hyphens
        var verificationCode = Input.Code.Replace(" ", string.Empty).Replace("-", string.Empty);

        var is2faTokenValid = await UserManager.VerifyTwoFactorTokenAsync(user, UserManager.Options.Tokens.AuthenticatorTokenProvider,
        verificationCode);

        if (!is2faTokenValid)
        {
            message = "Error: Verification code is invalid."; return;
        }

        await UserManager.SetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(user, true); var userId = await UserManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
        Logger.LogInformation("User with ID '{UserId}' has enabled 2FA with an authenticator app.", userId);

        message = "Your authenticator app has been verified.";

        if (await UserManager.CountRecoveryCodesAsync(user) == 0)
        {
            recoveryCodes = await UserManager.GenerateNewTwoFactorRecoveryCodesAsync(user, 10);
        }
        else
        {

            RedirectManager.RedirectToWithStatus("Account/Manage/TwoFactorAuthentication", message, HttpContext);
        }
    }

    private async ValueTask LoadSharedKeyAndQrCodeUriAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        // Load the authenticator key & QR code URI to display on the form
        var unformattedKey = await UserManager.GetAuthenticatorKeyAsync(user); if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(unformattedKey))
        {
            await UserManager.ResetAuthenticatorKeyAsync(user);
            unformattedKey = await UserManager.GetAuthenticatorKeyAsync(user);
        }

        sharedKey = FormatKey(unformattedKey!);

        var email = await UserManager.GetEmailAsync(user);

        authenticatorUri = GenerateQrCodeUri(email!, unformattedKey!); GenerateQRCode(authenticatorUri);
    }

    private string FormatKey(string unformattedKey)
    {
        var result = new StringBuilder(); int currentPosition = 0;
        while (currentPosition + 4 < unformattedKey.Length)
        {
            result.Append(unformattedKey.AsSpan(currentPosition, 4)).Append(' '); currentPosition += 4;
        }
        if (currentPosition < unformattedKey.Length)
        {
            result.Append(unformattedKey.AsSpan(currentPosition));
        }

        return result.ToString().ToLowerInvariant();
    }

    private string GenerateQrCodeUri(string email, string unformattedKey)
    {
        return string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, AuthenticatorUriFormat,
        UrlEncoder.Encode("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI"), UrlEncoder.Encode(email),
        unformattedKey);
    }

    private sealed class InputModel
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(7, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)][Display(Name = "Verification Code")] public string Code { get; set; } = "";
    }
}

Now I get:


Your answer is good, but you may improve it further by highlighting what you exactly modified in the C# code part, i.e. 1. adding the QRByte variable, 2. adding the GenerateQRCode function, 3. calling GenerateQRCode(authenticatorUri) at the end of OnValidSubmitAsync.

You also need to declare the variable QRByte

Does this actually work on Windows server? The use of System.Drawing raises a red flag.

I can shorten the Answer by @MartApon
1. Install Nuget package QRCoderNetCore
PM> NuGet\Install-Package QRCoderNetCore -Version 1.0.0

Do the following in the EnableAuthenticator.razor file
2. Add the following in the using area
@using QRCoder
@using System.Drawing.Imaging
@using System.Drawing

3. Create QRBytes property
   private string QRByte = "";


Add the method GenerateQRCode

4. Create method GenerateQRCode()
public void GenerateQRCode(string QRUrl)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(QRUrl))
    {
        using MemoryStream ms = new();
        QRCodeGenerator qrCodeGenerate = new();

        QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrCodeGenerate.CreateQrCode(QRUrl, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
        QRCode qrCode = new(qrCodeData);
        using Bitmap qrBitMap = qrCode.GetGraphic(20);
        qrBitMap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
        string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        QRByte = string.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", base64);
    }
}

5. Add the following in the place you want to display QRCode
    <div><img alt="" src="@QRByte" width="300" class="mb-5" /></div>
    <div data-url="@QRByte"></div>


Let's get the qrcode.js file and place it in the blazor project/wwwroot/js folder. My test sample is a blazor web app using InteractiveServerRenderMode, so that I had <script> part in App.razor.
<body>
    <Routes />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
    <script src="js/qrcode.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.generateQrcode = (url) => {
            var qrcode = new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrcode"), {
                text: url,
                width: 100,
                height: 100
            });
        };
    </script>
</body>

Then in my Home.razor I added js runtime and render mode.
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime JS
@rendermode InteractiveServer


<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
<p>@url</p>
<div id="qrcode" style="width:100px; height:100px; margin-top:15px;"></div>

Welcome to your new app.

@code {
    private string? url = "www.bing.com";  

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            url = "www.bing.com";
            await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("generateQrcode", url);
        }
    }
}

Then this is the test result.


call js method from .net: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Interactice Server rendermode is not working as I need to use static rendering for all Account pages, see https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/51476#issuecomment-1835666849

pls share more details about your blazor project, render mode, how do you write your Authentication scheme and related codes
